# Dealing with permissions with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a project for a music school and I have a table for students, a table for courses available and I was creating the table for teachers. My question is, how can i manage to "**link**" a teacher to a certain or more than one course, so that when the teacher logs in the admin page, he can only update and add information to the students that belong to the course/s that he is teaching.
My first thought was that I should have a field in the teachers table that could only contain values from the **courseID** (for example, if i want to register a guitar teacher and the ID of the guitar course is 3, i should have a field in the teachers table named **teacher_course_id** which would have the value 3).I also thought about having more than one teacher for a course, and if so, how can I give permissions to one teacher only (the teacher of that student) and not all the teachers from that especific course?
I don't really need the code for anything, I just wanted a a brief explanation on how could I do it. If I wasn't clear enough I can give more details in the comments

Comment: you can have a column in student table which will store courseID with teacherID , so if teacherID match ,only that teacher can see those students

Comment: @RaoDYC thats not a good idea - students should probably have ability to join more courses with different teachers

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? If you don't need any code, why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: That makes sense but I can't have a column to store the courseID in the students table because a student can have more than one course. I have a secondary table to associate that. And also everytime I register a teacher, I assume that I would have to do that association between the teacher and the students one by one...

Comment: This is covered in all basic SQL learning material. Look for some tutorials if you dont have a book. SO is not supposed to be a replacement for doing your own research/learning. How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Teachers and courses have either a many-to-many (a teacher can tech multiple courses and a course may be taught by more than one teacher) or if a course can be taught be only one teacher (this is a business decision, not a programming one), then a one-to-many relationship. You need to model your data based on your business decision.

Comment: Basically it sounds like you need to separate out "classes" from "courses"... So you'd end up with simple tables for `students | courses | teachers` and joining tables of `studentClasses | classes |  teacherClasses`. If that makes sense....

Answer (score 0):

You need one more table for relation between teachers and courses, smth like that:

**course**
id
title
...

**teacher**
id
name
...

**teacher_course**
course_id
teacher_id
can_edit 0/1
...

Answer (score 0):

You can create table with fields `teacher_id`, `course_id` with `Primary Key (teacher_id, course_id)`

Comment: You can. But as the OP is struggling with the basics, you should add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it